# python move characters based on string position

Tags: python, string, position, character, move

I am trying to move a special character from one position to another in a string. I want it to appear after the next character.  Here is my string:

```
"th i s. i s. a. n i c ^ e . s t r i ng."
```

This symbol can appear at any point.  I have been able to identify the next space but I still can't move it.

What I have done so far is this:

```
x= "th i s. i s. a. n i c ^ e . s t r i ng."
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == '^':
        j = i + 1
        if x[j] == ' ':
            j = j + 1
            while j < len(x) and x[j] != ' ':
                j = j + 1

            print "in the position " + str(i) + ", I found a hat: '" + str(x[i]) + "'"
            print "in the position " + str(j) + ", I found the next space: '" + str(x[j]) + "'"
            x.remove(i)
            x.insert('^', j)
        else:
            print 'somebody help!'
```

Comment: input `x= "th i s. i s. a. n i c ^ e . s t r i ng."` what do you want the output to be?

Comment: strings are non mutable ... you will need to make a new string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update]

Thank you for all the great responses.  I found a solution to my own question after messing with it for a while.  I hope this helps someone else! :-)

```
x= "th i s. i s. a. n i^ c e. s s t. s t r i ng."
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == '^':
        j = i + 1
        if x[j] == ' ':
            j = j + 1
            while j < len(x) and x[j] != ' ':
                j = j + 1
                print x
            x= x[0:i] + x[i+1:]
            x= x[0:j-1] + "^" + x[j-1:]
            print x
            exit()
```

result: 
th i s. i s. a. n i c^ e. s s t. s t r i ng.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable and they don't have any `remove` or `insert` method. So, you should convert your string to a list first and then you can use `list.remove` and `list.insert`.

```
>>> x = "th i s. i s. a. n i c ^ e . s t r i ng."
>>> list(x)
['t', 'h', ' ', 'i', ' ', 's', '.', ' ', 'i', ' ', 's', '.', ' ', 'a', '.', ' ', 'n', ' ', 'i', ' ', 'c', ' ', '^', ' ', 'e', ' ', '.', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', '.']
```

And finally after modifying the list you can join it back using `str.join`.

**Errors in your code:**

```
 x.remove('^')     # you should remove '^' here, not the index
 x.insert(j, '^')  # first argument is the index, second is the item
```

Comment: If there is a single special character `x.split('^')` will probably be faster. Only the second sub-string will need to be analyzed and updated before joining the two back together.

Comment: I am new to python and noticing that the gap between functions for lists and strings is somewhat scary but can be overcome with a little know-how.  Thank you for the great answer, this will surely be helpful in future codes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue but here are a couple of examples on how you can move a character within a sequence of characters.

## Moving Character To Index

```
def move_char_index(chars, char, new_index):
    # Convert character sequence to list type.
    char_list = list(chars)
    # Get the current index of the target character.
    old_index = char_list.index(char)
    # Remove the target character from the character list.
    char = char_list.pop(old_index)
    # Insert target character at a new location.
    char_list.insert(new_index, char)
    # Convert character list back to str type and return.
    return ''.join(char_list)
```

**Examples:**

```
chars = 'th i s. i s. a. n i c  ^e . s t r i ng.'
char = '^'

# Move character to the end of the string.
print move_char_index(chars, char, len(chars)) 
# Result: th i s. i s. a. n i c  e . s t r i ng.^

# Move character to the start of the string.
print move_char_index(chars, char, 0) 
# Result:  ^th i s. i s. a. n i c  e . s t r i ng.
```

## Moving Character By Increment

```
def move_char_by_increment(chars, char, increment):
    # Convert character sequence to list type.
    char_list = list(chars)
    # Get the current index of the target character.
    old_index = char_list.index(char)
    # Remove the target character from the character list.
    char = char_list.pop(old_index)
    # Insert target character at a new location.
    new_index = old_index + increment
    char_list.insert(new_index, char)
    # Convert character list back to str type and return.
    return ''.join(char_list)
```

**Examples:**

```
chars = 'th i s. i s. a. n i c  ^e . s t r i ng.'
char = '^'

# Move character forward by 1.
print move_char_by_increment(chars, char, 1) 
# Result: th i s. i s. a. n i c  e^ . s t r i ng.

# Move character backward by 1.
print move_char_by_increment(chars, char, -1) 
# Result: th i s. i s. a. n i c ^ e . s t r i ng.
```